# Google Calendar to Google Sheet (Multiple Emails for specific events)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to export multiple email addresses for multiple events; I publish this fortnightly for members across the state and need to include the event secretary email.

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){
// Reference Websites:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event
var mycal = "***REDACTED***";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("April 24, 2023 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("June 30, 2023 23:59:59 CST"));
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.clearContents();
var header = [["Event Start", "Event Title", "Event Location", "Event Description"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,4);
range.setValues(header);
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var details=[[events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getDescription()]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,4);
range.setValues(details);}
}function onOpen() {
  Browser.msgBox('App Instructions - Please Read This Message', '1) Click Tools then Script Editor\\n2) Read/update the code with your desired values.\\n3) Then when ready click Run export_gcal_to_gsheet from the script editor.', Browser.Buttons.OK);}
```

I do not code, I am self-taught, but I have modified the above to include a new Column "Guest List", unfortunately it always results in the one answer "Event Guest".

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){
// Reference Websites:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event
var mycal = "**redacted**";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("April 24, 2023 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("May 31, 2023 23:59:59 CST"));
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.clearContents();
var header = [["Event Start", "Event Title", "Event Location", "Event Description", "Guest List"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,5);
range.setValues(header);
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var details=[[events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getGuestList()]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
range.setValues(details);}
}function onOpen() {
  Browser.msgBox('App Instructions - Please Read This Message', '1) Click Tools then Script Editor\\n2) Read/update the code with your desired values.\\n3) Then when ready click Run export_gcal_to_gsheet from the script editor.', Browser.Buttons.OK);}
```

Can you please advise how I could incorporate the below into the above, or is there another way, so I am able to obtain multiple email addresses into a single Google Sheet Cell:

```
var guests = events[i].getGuestList();
var guestEmails;

for (var j = 0; j < guests.length; j++){
    guestEmails.push(guests[j].getEmail());
    Logger.log(guestEmails[j]);
}
```

With Thanks, A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, when `setValues` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high.
- `getGuestList()` returns an array of CalendarApp.EventGuest[]. So, in this modification, this is converted to a string.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function export_gcal_to_gsheet() {
  var mycal = "**redacted**";

  // Retrieve values from events.
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("April 24, 2023 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("May 31, 2023 23:59:59 CST"));
  var values = [["Event Start", "Event Title", "Event Location", "Event Description", "Guest List"]];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    values.push([events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getGuestList().map(e => e.getEmail()).join(",")]);
  }

  // Put values to the active sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getGuestList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getguestlist)